# PHP date locale to dutch

Tags: php, date, setlocale

I've been searching for a workaround, but unfortunately with no luck. When we use the `date("M");` or `date("D");` function, the output is as follows:

```
Tue
Dec
```

What we want is to transform this locale to dutch, for example: Tue to Dinsdag and Dec to December. We've tried to setlocale already (also we have installed this on server side).

Does someone have a workaround for this?

Comment: But please note the second answer, not the accepted one.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I needed in order to fix this issue.